# Is there a way to allow Zuul to preserve upstream cache headers when spring security is being used

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

When using Zuul (`cloud Edgware.SR3`) in spring boot (`1.5.10.RELEASE`), is it possible to preserve the cache control headers of an upstream system given that spring security is being used.

I think you can set `zuul.ignore-security-headers=true` but, in my understanding that will remove ALL security related headers (such as HSTS, Frame blocking, xss protection, HPKP etc).

I just want to remove the default spring security no cache headers and favour the up stream response which includes public cache control (for 1 year for example).

Thanks.

Comment: please dont cross post, i already responded to you on github

Comment: I was hoping for a different (perhaps wider) audience on stack overflow than i'd get on the spring issues list.

Comment: For anyone who find this and wants to see the other post: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2799